Escape version string that Telegram interprets as URL
Potion Craft 2.0 was released today and I wrote to two of my acquantances

Hey, version 2.0.1.1 has been released!

knowing that they had long uninstalled the game, having grown tired of waiting for an update that might never come.
... Telegram interprets this as the URL https://2.0.1.1 and generates a clickable link. In this particular case that is "harmless": There is a server there, but it does not answer. I'd rather not "accidentally" link to who-knows-where and even if I do not get malware in retaliation, it just seems rude to bother some random server.
How do I escape the string '2.0.1.1' so that Telegram displays 2.0.1.1 and does not insert a hyperlink?
I tried \2.0.1.1, """"2.0.1.1"""", 2\.0\.1\.1 to no avail.
Unfortunately Google search is still poisoned by "how do I prevent the link preview thumbnail to be generated", which used to be a problem some years ago.

It interprets it as an IP address. To not do that, the simpliest way would be to just use something like 2.0.1 . 1 or v2.0.1.1 to break the format.
Another very simple solution is to use something you also used here - classic Markdown inline/short code formatting: `2.0.1.1`

First paragraph seems to be superfluous. Second paragraph is the correct answer. Accepted. Will upvote once superfluous part is removed. ... I went ahead and also tried triple backticks as on GitHub, Gitlab, etc. - also works and even has syntax highlighting - might want to add that as a new second paragraph.

No, both are correct answers, anyone can use what they desire. Backticks are actually harder to type on e.g. phone... IMO the v version is the most optimal one in terms of average speed and readability.
